# Unable to click on element - Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm trying to click on a Checkout Button. This is how it looks like :

[image]

And HTML snippet for the same :

```
<div id="buy-button-next">
   <span data-reactroot="">
      <div data-cid="buy-button--enabled" style="align-items: center; border-style: solid; border-width: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; flex-basis: auto; flex-direction: column; flex-shrink: 0; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: relative; min-height: 0px; min-width: 0px;">
         <div style="align-items: stretch; border-style: solid; border-width: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; flex-basis: auto; flex-direction: column; flex-shrink: 0; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: relative; min-height: 0px; min-width: 340px;">
            <button data-cid="button.buy_button" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); border: none; cursor: pointer; outline: 0px; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);">
               <div style="align-items: stretch; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; flex-basis: auto; flex-direction: column; flex-shrink: 0; margin: 0px; padding: 4px; position: relative; min-height: 0px; min-width: 0px; background-color: rgb(52, 52, 52); border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); border-radius: 3px; height: 50px; transition: background-color 0.2s ease, border-color 0.2s ease;">
                  <div style="align-items: stretch; border-style: solid; border-width: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; flex-basis: auto; flex-direction: column; flex-shrink: 0; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: absolute; min-height: 0px; min-width: 0px; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); border-radius: 3px; bottom: -1px; left: -1px; opacity: 1; right: -1px; top: -1px; transition: background-color 0.2s ease, opacity 0.2s ease; z-index: 1;"></div>
                  <div style="align-items: center; border-style: solid; border-width: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; flex-basis: auto; flex-direction: column; flex-shrink: 0; margin: 0px; padding: 0px 21px; position: relative; min-height: 0px; min-width: 0px; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); border-radius: 3px; height: 100%; justify-content: center; transition: background-color 0.2s ease, border-color 0.2s ease, color 0.2s ease; z-index: 2;">
                     <div style="align-items: stretch; border-style: solid; border-width: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; flex-basis: auto; flex-direction: column; flex-shrink: 0; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: absolute; min-height: 0px; min-width: 0px; align-self: center; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-2px);"></div>
                     <span style="max-width: 100%; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: &quot;Klarna Sans&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 700; font-size: 16px; opacity: 1; transition: color 0.2s ease; visibility: visible; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; text-rendering: geometricPrecision; text-size-adjust: none;">Place Order</span>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </button>
         </div>
         <div style="align-items: stretch; border-style: solid; border-width: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; flex-basis: auto; flex-direction: column; flex-shrink: 0; min-height: 0px; min-width: 0px; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); width: 100%; height: 30px;"></div>
      </div>
   </span>
</div>
```

All content loads in an iFrame, So I'm switching in iFrame as well.

```
driver.switchTo().frame("klarna-checkout-iframe");
```

but the button have weird html.

Code trial I did:

```
css=button[data-cid='button.buy_button'] span

xpath=//div/span[contains(text(),'Place Order')]
```

I'm getting Timeout exception while waiting for presence of this element.

> Timed out after 35 seconds waiting for presence of element located by:
>   By.cssSelector: button[data-cid='button.buy_button'] span

Comment: Share the frame switching code and exception you got

Comment: @AshokkumarGanesan, update in question please check

Comment: Make sure the button is inside the `iframe`, and that there aren't any other nested `iframe`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have shared and your code trials, first you have to induce *WebDriverwait* for the *frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt*  and then moving forward possibly you are going to invoke `click()` on the *Checkout Button*, so you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and  you can use either of the following solution:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("klarna-checkout-iframe")));
//new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.name("klarna-checkout-iframe")));
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@id='buy-button-next']//button[@data-cid='button.buy_button']//span[contains(.,'Place Order')]"))).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
css = button[data-cid='button.buy_button']>div>div>span
```

And before clicking you can also verify the text 'Place Order' and then go for the click.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you try 
`#buy-button-next span div div button`

Answer (score 0):

After switching to an iframe, you can use the below xpath to identify the element

**Xpath:**

```
//div[@id='buy-button-next']//button//span[contains(text(),'Place Order')]
```